# Google Play Game Services's invite dialog doesn't show any friend

Tags: c++, ios, google-play-games

I'm trying to get GPG C++'s invitation system to work correctly for an iOS game.
I tried to call RealtimeMultiplayerManager::ShowPlayerSelectUI() to open a dialog to select friends to be invited. However, the dialog doesn't show any friend, only "Auto-Pick" option. I have several Google test accounts in the same circle, and they are already listed as testers in Google Play Console. The game is still in development.
Does anyone know what wrong?

Thanks,

Here is the code:

```
m_gameServices->RealTimeMultiplayer().ShowPlayerSelectUI(1, 1, true,
                                                                 [this](gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::PlayerSelectUIResponse const &
                                                                        response){

                                                                     HQRemote::Log("inviting friends %d", response.status);

                                                                     if (gpg::IsError(response.status))
                                                                     {
                                                                         handleError((BaseStatus::StatusCode)response.status);
                                                                     }
                                                                     else{
                                                                         auto config = gpg::RealTimeRoomConfig::Builder()
                                                                                        .PopulateFromPlayerSelectUIResponse(response)
                                                                                        .Create();

                                                                         createRoom(config);
                                                                     }
                                                                 });
```

Update 21/3/2016:
Friends finally appear on the dialog's UI after 3 days of development. Why there is a delay like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your `RealTimeMultiplayerManager::ShowPlayerSelectUI` method if you misconfigured something. Here is a sample snippet.

```
void Engine::InviteFriend() {
  service_->RealTimeMultiplayer().ShowPlayerSelectUI(
      MIN_PLAYERS, MAX_PLAYERS, true,
      [this](gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::PlayerSelectUIResponse const &
                 response) {
        LOGI("inviting friends %d", response.status);
            // Your code to handle the users's selection goes here.
      });
}
```

You can also look into this [Adding Real-time Multiplayer Support to Your Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/realtimeMultiplayer#invite_players_option) documentation to check your configuration.

Comment: I tried to run their ButtonClicker sample also the same, no friend showing. However, quick match works for both ButtonClicker and my game, the Game Services is able to choose random people to connect to each others.
Game Services seems to have some SendReliableMessage bugs also. It always return ERR_NOT_AUTHORIZED even though if I hadn't authorize, I would not have been able to create any quick match.

Comment: Can you provide the logs and your code in `RealtimeMultiplayerManager::ShowPlayerSelectUI()` method?

Comment: "inviting friends 1",  the callback is however only triggered when I choose "Auto-Pick" and start the game.